# wrapMethod Meteor methods

Tags: javascript, methods, meteor

I was looking into this presentation, [building large meteor applications](http://meteor.redandivory.com/#/7/7), and I like the idea of the wrapMethod(), but it seems like I can't use it like on the example.

Here is my code.

```
Meteor.methods({

  'EX.Accounts.Methods.updateProfileData' : function(userId, firstName, secondName) {
    check([firstName, secondName], [String]);
    Meteor.users.update(userId, {
      $set: {
        'profile.firstName': firstName,
        'profile.lastName': secondName,
        'profile.isRegisted': true
      }
    });
  }
});

EX.Accounts.Methods.updateUserProfile =   EX.wrapMethod('EX.Accounts.Methods.updateProfileData');
```

But I got this error.

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'wrapMethod'

I'm missing something I know but just can't find any information about this `"wrapMethod"`

**Update**

Also try with

```
_.extend(EX.Accounts.Methods,{
  updateUserProfile : EX.Accounts.Methods.updateProfileData
});
```

Which doesn't return an error but I don't see the method on the global namespace.

EX.Accounts.Methods is clear with no methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the developer created the method `wrapMethod` on his PB obejct. As you can [see here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=wrapMethod) there is nothing called `wrapMethod` in Meteor. I guess they wrote something like this:

```
PB.wrapMethod = function wrapMethod (meteorMethod) {
  return function wrappedMeteorMethod (/*arugments*/) {
    Meteor.apply(meteorMethod, arguments)
  }
}
```

I think it's kinda neat.
Btw.: As you can see i like to name my anonymous functions. Makes debugging nicer.

Answer (score 1):

In ES6 this becomes a beauty:

```
wrapMethod(method) {
    return (...args) => Meteor.call(method, ...args);
}
```